# Find a topological space X and a compact subset A in X such that closure of A is not compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Find a topological space X and a compact subset A in X such that closure of  A is not compact.

I first concluded that we must have X to be a non compact and a non Hausdorff space so that closure of A is not compact.
I have been trying to look for an appropriate A such that closure of A is X and is hence not compact.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Finite sets are always compact. But they can be dense, if you don't require $T_1$.